# How can I parse the below JSON output in JAVA and display all RefNo in jsp

Tags: java, json, spring

{Status=200,
dataVal=
{"TotalCount":3,
"Entities":
{"Type":50,"Message":"Submitted for Dispute","TransactionId":"2207280001","RefNo":"0110A2226A28","Amount":932.0,"AccountNo":"1049019264010","Vat":43.0},
{"Type":50,"Message":"Submitted for Dispute","TransactionId":"2207280003","RefNo":"5815B2220B23","Amount":479.0,"AccountNo":"1049016101100","Vat":0.0},
{"Type":50,"TransactionId":"2207280002","RefNo":"5815B2220B24","Amount":531.0,"AccountNo":"1049016101080","Vat":0.0}
}
}

Comment: This is not a valid json. Entities should be an array of objects like this `"Entities":[{},{}]` once you have a valid json you can use `fasterxml.jackson` or `Gson` library to convert this string into `JSONObject` or you can map json string to `POJO`

Answer (score 0):

This is not a valid json. Entities should be an array of objects like this `"Entities":[{},{}]` once you have a valid json you can use `fasterxml.jackson` or Gson library to convert this string into `JSONObject` or you can map json string to `POJO`

Use string functions to convert your string to Valid JSON. Final json string should have this structure

```
{
    "TotalCount":3, 
    "Entities": [
        {"Type":50,"Message":"Submitted for Dispute","TransactionId":"2207280001","RefNo":"0110A2226A28","Amount":932.0,"AccountNo":"1049019264010","Vat":43.0},
        {"Type":50,"Message":"Submitted for Dispute","TransactionId":"2207280003","RefNo":"5815B2220B23","Amount":479.0,"AccountNo":"1049016101100","Vat":0.0},
        {"Type":50,"TransactionId":"2207280002","RefNo":"5815B2220B24","Amount":531.0,"AccountNo":"1049016101080","Vat":0.0}
    ] 
}
```

To get the above structure from json that you posted in question you can do something like this

```
String jsonString = Your_Json_String_From_Request;
//Note: below code is space sensitive and written according to the string that you posted in question. 
//You might have to tweak it if the string in replace() function's first parameter has extra or no space.
jsonString = jsonString.substring(jsonString.lastIndexOf("=")+1).trim().replace("\"Entities\": {","\"Entities\": [{").replace("} } }","}]}");
```

You class structure will go something like this:

**DataVal Class**

```
public class DataVal{
    public int TotalCount;
    public List<Entities> Entities;
}
```

**Entities Class**

```
public class Entities{
    public int Type;
    public String Message;
    public String TransactionId;
    public String RefNo;
    public float Amount;
    public String AccountNo;
    public float Vat;
}
```

**Function to Convert Json String To DataVal Class (Using Gson Library)**

```
public DataVal deserializeJson(String jsonString) {
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    DataVal dataVal = gson.fromJson(jsonString, DataVal.class);
    return dataVal;
}
```

**Now call this function with your jsonString**

```
DataVal dataVal = deserializeJson(jsonString)
```

Now add `dataVal` to model attribute of the target view.